# jQuery UI Sortable snap on drag element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it any way to take a snap while you dragging element. For example, element itself too big while Im dragging it, so it will show only small copy of it. Or if I starting to drag element but I want to show something different while Im dragging it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `helper` function you can control the dragged element:

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    helper: function(ev, ui) {
      return ui.clone().text('This item is currently being dragged')
    }
  });
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
})
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```